# How to connect to managed account in stripe and make a payment?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

First of all, I'm Sorry for my english.

I want to create a charge in Stripe from account A to account B. The account A is a mananaged account. The account B can be any of multiple accounts. But when I try to create the charge with the destination parameter the API resturn an error. Says:

```
"error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "The destination param must be a connected account.",
    "param": "destination"
  }
```

How I could connect the destination account (Account B) to get this??. I'm using the php api stripe to this. Next this is the example code that I using. Thanks in advance:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_ACCOUNT_A_KEY');

// Charge the order:
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    // 'source'    => $token,
    'customer'  => 'cus_ID_CUSTOMER_TO_GET_PAYMENT',
    "amount" => 100000,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "description" => "from account A to account B",
    'destination' => 'acct_ID_DESTINATION_ACCOUNT'
    )
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($charge);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: The two accounts need to be connected with Stripe Connect (probably using the Standalone approach).  Take a look at the guide here--

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts

Once you connect the two accounts, your code will probably work.

Comment: Hi @korben, the standalone account allow stripe to handle everything, the connection, create users, etc, etc. We can't do that, because all this process must be transparent to user. It must be in background proccess (like behind scene) and I think this is possible with managed account and the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have gone through stripe documentations you clearly will have seen there are three types of charges in Stripe connect.

- Direct Charges
- Destination Charges
- Seperate Charges

In your case, you will have to use destination charges. You could use

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                  "amount" => 1000,
                  "currency" => "usd",
                  "source" => "cus_ID_CUSTOMER_TO_GET_PAYMENT",
                  "destination" => array(
                    "account" => "{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}",
                  ),
            ));
```

to charge a customer on behalf of your **connected account**.

Comment: thanks @VishnuR for your help. This is what I need. Thank you.